# Pass variables into and out of exec

Tags: python

Given the following code

```
a = 100
b = 200

snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

exec(snip)
print(c)
```

how can I pass values into exec, and get values out of exec, without using global scope? In effect, I want to be able to explicitly control the entire scope `exec` has access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, global scope is used with exec

```
a = 100
b = 200

snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

exec(snip)
print(c)
```

However, this can be problematic in some use cases. `exec` allows you to pass in a dictionary defining the global and local scope. Here's an example:

```
snip = '''
c = a+b
'''

input_globals = {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
output_locals = {}

exec(snip, input_globals, output_locals)
print(output_locals)
```

This results in the following output:

```
{'c': 102}
```

this effectively allows one to use exec with it's own scope, without working on and modifying global scope.

You can read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) for more detail.